# Get First Hidden Field

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
    $(document.body).click(function() {
       $(".content").each(function(i) {
           $(this).
       });
    });
```

How can I retrieve the value of the first hidden field within $(this)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:hidden` and `:first` filter selectors like this:

```
$(document.body).click(function() {
   $(".content").each(function(i) {
       $(':hidden:first', $(this)).val();
   });
});
```

Comment: So would I just declare, for example var v = (':hidden:first', $(this)).val();?

Comment: @Sarfraz - Typo on your third code line, missing the '$'.  Also, I might note that '$(this)' is unnecessary there.  Using just 'this' would suffice.

Comment: On the same note, how can I get the first image within this?

Comment: @George: Just replace `:hidden` with `img`